# Using Graph API Beta to update a Channel displayname and moderationsettings

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams, beta

I have this call to update a Teams's Channel "displayName" & " moderationSettings' as follow:-

[image: johnjohnPter_0-1709409044913.png]

so my question is there an API call (not-Beta) to do the same action? and in the future what will happen when the beta became a major release? will the above URL which contain /beta/ breaks? or it will keep working?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`moderationSettings` is currently available only in [beta](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/channel?view=graph-rest-beta#properties), so for now you can't replace the URL from `beta` to `v1.0`.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}
```

The Graph team **make no guarantees** that a beta feature will be promoted to the v1.0 version and usually there is no official announcement that some feature is generally available in v1.0.

Once the feature is generally available in v1.0, the beta version will keep working.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/versioning-and-support?view=graph-rest-beta